# Api Gateway access UserAgent and Ip from Custom Authorizer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

In **Body Mapping Template** of a ApiGateway Resource I can pass the user-agent and ip of the client to my Lambda function.

```
{
    "client_ip":"$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params('X-Forwarded-For'))",
    "user_agent" : "$util.escapeJavaScript($input.params('User-Agent'))"
}
```

Is it possible to pass this information before? To the Lambda function used as **Custom Authorizer** for ApiGateway?

Comment: I think you only can pass in one parameter as a token to your *Custom Authorizer*

Answer (score 0):

You can't currently modify the contents of what's being sent to authorizer. Only available things are `methodArn`, `authorizatonToken` and `type`.